# How to use variables for parameter in execute a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've declared and set some variables. Then I want to use that variable value as a parameter in executing a stored procedure. But I always get error

> Must declare the scalar variable.

Here are my variables:

```
--declare variables for parameter @listweek
declare @tgl_other varchar(50);

--set variables for parameter @listweekset 
set @tgl_other = (select top 1 ltrim(rtrim(cast(numweek as char)))+'-('+rangeweek+')' from tbl_weeklyflash where year(dates) = year(getdate()) order by numweek desc);

--the variable values should be like this 30-(01-03-2012 - 08-03-2012) 
--and this value that I want to use as parameter value in executing stored procedure
```

and this is the executing stored procedure:

```
insert into my_table (field1, field2, field3)
EXEC my_store_procedure @tgl_other
-- the parameter for my_store_procedure is like '30-(01-03-2012 - 08-03-2012)'
```

Is it my variables not correct? or I've wrong way to use variable for parameter?

UPDATE:

if I execute this query:

```
declare @tgl_other varchar(50);
set @tgl_other = (select top 1 ltrim(rtrim(cast(numweek as char)))+'-('+rangeweek+')' from tbl_weeklyflash where year(dates) = year(getdate()) order by numweek desc);
EXEC my_store_procedure @tgl_other
```

it works fine, but if I add `INSERT INTO..` statements it won't work. Why it happens?

UPDATE II:
here is the whole query that I try to run

```
declare @tgl_other varchar(50);
set @tgl_other = (select top 1 ltrim(rtrim(cast(numweek as char)))+'-('+rangeweek+')' from tbl_weeklyflash where year(dates) = year(getdate()) order by numweek desc);
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable
GO
INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2)    
EXEC my_store_procedure @tgl_other
GO
```

Comment: The sql seems to be correct .Are you executing the entire sql batch or just the insert into... statements ?

Comment: @praveen I executing the entire sql batch. I've update my question for more detail

Comment: Can you show an example output from the stored procedure - only a couple rows will do...

Comment: Can you confirm that `@tgl_id` and `@tgl_sg` have no significance?

Comment: DO you have a `GO` somewhere between declaring your variables and the call to execute the stored procedure? Variables are only visible inside their scope - when you have a `GO` in there, that terminates the previous batch/scope and starts a new one - and in that new one, the variables aren't visible/declared anymore...

Comment: @praveen the SP only shows the table with parameter

Comment: @ChrisMoutray I've update my question for more detail :)

Comment: @marc_s yes, I use `GO` in my query. Would you check my update in question? thanks :)

Comment: @blankon91: **remove** that `GO` and I think you should be fine then!

Comment: @blankon91 : Go groups sql commands into batch .You cant define a variable in 1 batch and use it in another

Comment: @marc_s it works :) thank you, please submit an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @praveen so I just need to remove the `GO` like @marc_s said before? thank you for the explanation :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DO you have a `GO` somewhere between declaring your variables and the call to execute the stored procedure? Variables are only visible inside their scope - when you have a GO in there, that terminates the previous batch/scope and starts a new one - and in that new one, the variables aren't visible/declared anymore..

So try this instead:

```
declare @tgl_other varchar(50);

set @tgl_other = (select top 1 ltrim(rtrim(cast(numweek as char)))+'-('+rangeweek+')' from tbl_weeklyflash where year(dates) = year(getdate()) order by numweek desc);

TRUNCATE TABLE mytable

-- GO     remove this GO to make it work!

INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2)    
EXEC my_store_procedure @tgl_other
GO
```